# Error CS0103 when debugging most variables in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to debug code in a cshtml file. I set a breakpoint and it breaks. But when I try to watch a variable it gives the CS0103 error. This is happening all the time not just in this part of the code.

I have set it to use managed compatibility and made sure I am in debug instead of release. I have looked at it on google and it is set up the way it should be as far as I know. I am a newbie to C# and debugging cshtml files.

```
if (@Model.GranteeDeed1 > 0) {
    var fe = fundEntities.filter(function(obj) { return obj.FundEntityID == @Model.GranteeDeed1; });
    $("#lblGranteeDeed1").text(fe[0].EntityName);
    $("#txtGranteeDeed1 option[value='" + fe[0].FundEntityID  + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
}
```

I want to see the value of either obj.FundEntityID or (fe[0].EntityName). I can see the value of @Model.GranteeDeed1.

Comment: Hi, which VS do you use, VS for MAC or VS for windows? If it's vs for windows, right-click project=>properties=>build tab=>advanced, make sure the `debug information` is set to Full instead of Portable...

Comment: Windows. And it is already set to Full. That was one of the hints I got from googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those two variables appear to be Javascript. You will want to use the developer tool in your browser (F12 in Chrome/Firefox/Edge on Windows, not sure what the equivalent is on Mac). In Chrome it's the "Sources" tab and in Firefox it's the "Debugger" tab.

Here are some links:

- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Comment: IE says that the EntityName was unable to get the value. Chrome did not give any indication of a problem. But I will look again at the Sources tab, tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I knew the @Model was a javascript variable I just thought the others were c# server-side variables.

Comment: `@Model` *is* a server-side variable. The `@` symbol is a shortcut to put the value of a server-side variable onto the page. If you look at the actual HTML, you'll see that it renders as something like `if (5 > 0) {` (whatever the value of `@Model.GranteeDeed1` is).

Comment: @howcheng- Thanks for the explanation. I did see that it replaced it with the value from the db.

Comment: I found that a Json query is coming back blank. But when I step through the code it appears to be populating the list and the value that is in GranteeDeed1 is in the list. See below
var fundEntities = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(((List<P.Models.GetFundEntityOptionsResult>)ViewBag.FundEntities).Select(f => new { FundEntityID = f.ID, EntityName = f.EntityName, InvestorId = f.InvestorId, InvestorName = f.InvestorName }).Where(f => f.InvestorName == Model.InvestorName).OrderBy(f => f.EntityName).ToList()))');
var fundEntities = JSON.parse('[]');