# Watch window at debugging: CS0103: The name '<any local>' does not exists in the current context

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2022, watch, .net-4.8

Am using:

`Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit), Version 17.4.2` with

`.NET Framework, Version 4.8.09032.`

There was an update yesterday, 02-12-2022, with I installed through the 'Visual Studio Installer'.

After this I can't watch local variables in the 'Watch' window while debugging. It gives me a CS0103 error (see image below).

Also in the window 'Locals' they do not appear.

(**edit**: Have posted the code of `StringParser` here [Watch window CS0103 - follow up to exclude my code as problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694938/watch-window-cs0103-follow-up-to-exclude-my-code-as-problem))

---

The solution is very simple, it consists out of two projects:

`Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)`

`Windows Forms Control Library (.NET Framework)`

The latter is linked to the first ofcourse. The control library contains `StringParser`.

---

Basically, the next code is all of the forms project. It is just test code while creating the `StringParser`. Prior to the update, this worked fine, as is when having `parser` as global of the `Form1`.

When declaring the local variable `parser` and instantiating it as global of the Form1, there is no `CS0103` on that variable.

---

The next two questions adresses this problem.

[VS 2015 Update 2 - Variable does not exist when debugging, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463286/vs-2015-update-2-variable-does-not-exist-when-debugging-why)

[Error CS0103 when debugging most variables in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397723/error-cs0103-when-debugging-most-variables-in-visual-studio-2019)

While I suspect the first does describe my situation. Haven't tried the solution as it is a  different version.

The second does not adress this issue.

---

```cs
public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    StringParser parser = new StringParser();
    parser.Content = filecontent;

    string token = "";
    while (!parser.Next('<'))
    {
                
        parser.Next('>');
        token = parser.Token;

    }

}
```

[image: Debugger Watch Window]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022 Report bugs like that to Microsoft.

Comment: Anyone know how I can find what the last version was before the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this error according to the code. Maybe you can provide more information about `StringParser` to help us reproduce the problem and give more suggestions.

You can try to [Refresh watch values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2022#bkmk_refreshWatch):
select the refresh icon, or press the spacebar or you can select Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls in Tools > Options > Debugging > General and try again.

If they don't work you can report this on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report).

And if you want to rollback to the vs used before you can choose more > Rollback to previous version in vs installer:
[image]

Comment: Will review my code first as I have noticed with a new project no problem. A new project and copying in my code, all in one application project, same problem. Before reporting a bug I believe it's a must to exclude as many possibilities as possible. Exspecially as I am not a professional due to both, learning and not passing throu nonsense. If you say to post the code, no problem, I will do so and enter the link here to the new question.

Comment: Am not rolling back until I am sure. Have posted the code of `StringParser` here [Watch window CS0103 - follow up to exclude my code as problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694938/watch-window-cs0103-follow-up-to-exclude-my-code-as-problem)

Answer (score 2):

It's a regression in `17.4` V.S.
WinForms repo issue: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/8354
Roslyn repo issue: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/66109

---

Fixed in 17.4.**5**.